# What are some good replacement parts for the given circuit?

Tags: simulation, memristor

I'm trying to simulate Chua's Memrsitor paper's MR mutator. The parts used in that paper are very old so I'm having trouble finding some of those specific parts in my local area and online. I want to know, can I use any Op-Amp, mosfet and other transistors to get similar results? I have never worked on "mutator" circuits so I don't exactly know how they work.

[Link to the paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1083337)

[image: Circuit I'm trying to emulate]

Also in general, is there a website or some easy way to find equivalent circuit parts, like for example I enter the parts code and it would list all the equivalent parts

Comment: If the components are really old, you're best bet is a search on internet for any datahseets avail, then with the parameters from the datasheets visit Mouser, Digi-Key, Farnell (electronics suppliers)

Comment: I predict you'll have the most difficulty replacing the JFETs, which are not widely used devices these days. 2N3819s are [still available](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/nte-electronics-inc/2N3819/11647880), but the 2N5464s are not. A J176 *might* be a workable substitute, but I can't say for sure without putting more effort into this than I'm willing to right now.

Comment: The "Nexus SQ-10a" is a very early (and consequently not very good, by today's standards) op amp, and can probably be replaced with any commonly available op amp that supports adequate voltage ranges. A 741 might even work, though I'd go for something a bit higher-quality than that.

Comment: Not only you can replace any of these components with modern ones with similar parameters, but you will have better quality for much cheaper. Original components tend to be expensive. A search according to parameters will give you plenty of offers.

Answer (score 1):

Stopping short of taking a close look at operation, I can still offer some observations on the building blocks.

**Op-amp**

The op-amp appears to be very ordinary; a uA741 would do, or even LM358, or a LF412, TL072 or etc. with suitable adjustments for their somewhat faster speed (if necessary).

Philbrick was an old name in operational amplifiers, ancient even; or perhaps better said, early innovators in the space.  Their first products were vacuum tube based, in fact, but by the time of this paper, they were making packaged and hybrid modules.  Here's a forum post describing the unit:
https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/philbrick-nexus-sq-10a.39957/

They don't have much data to offer, but there is in fact an archive website dedicated to the company, and provide a link to this informative catalog page (page 8 in particular): 
http://www.philbrickarchive.org/1972%20product%20guide.pdf#page=8 
The parameters are recognizable in modern terms, and indeed they look similar to a µA741 or the like (well, minus the absent E<sub>os</sub> parameter(!)).

**Diodes**

I don't know what an "OMC-V" is.  Possibly OMC was a semiconductor brand back in the day, I'm not sure; I don't see any hits.  (But with such strong recency bias as Google has these days, that's not too surprising.)  We can look at the surrounding circuit to get some idea what they were after:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPwGVs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[disregard component values/types, defaults only]

J1 and J2 are complementary source followers, with their drain currents wired to BJTs to multiply those currents by h<sub>FE</sub>.  The resulting composite transistor has gm*h<sub>FE</sub> gain, a simple way to get high output currents from ~nil input currents (JFETs draw little gate current, making them handy in buffer and analog computer circuits like this).  One of the characteristics of JFETs is a negative V<sub>GS(th)</sub>, which also has a wide variable range; we would thus want to put some voltage offset between the sources, to set quiescent current, but we will also need to select the JFETs to match them to each other (to reduce offset voltage between gate and output (the diode mid tap)), and to set bias appropriately.

So, it seems likely the diodes were just Si PN diodes, to set a bias around 1.5V per JFET.

Offhand, 2N3819 is a 2-20mA N-JFET, so 2N5464 must be its complement P-channel.  (Checking, this isn't very true: 2N3819 is 2-20mA 25V, while 2N5464 was 2-9mA 60V.  Within the operating range of this circuit, and with selected parts, they can still match well enough; true complements I don't think matter here.)

2N4236/9 are TO-39 package (metal can) medium-power BJTs; a 2N2219/2N2905 might be a more current equivalent, or BD139/140 (TO-126 package) or TIP29/30 (TO-220 package), or a variety of more modern parts.

Probably one could just as well remove Q1-Q4 entirely, adjusting resistor values upwards so as not to need so much load current in the first place.  In that case, higher memristance will be modeled.  Or use a more powerful A2 to the same end.

For the first and last such sets (Q1-Q4, Q9-Q12), emitters are common to the supplies, and the only function seems to be a unity-gain (voltage) buffer (or a little bit less than unity, since even with the current-boosting effect, the JFETs will still drop some voltage).  Presumably they could be replaced by op-amp voltage followers, and in particular, the combination with A2 could be replaced by a higher-current op-amp that is simply widely available these days.  (Even many "jellybean" ICs offer 50mA+ output, generously more than the SQ-10A's 5mA.)

The other two sets are biased differently: Q5-Q8 use a 3.9V 1W zener diode plus 20Ω, and Q9-Q12, a 3.3V 1W zener plus 20Ω, instead of four series diodes.  Since these are (mostly) connected to capacitors, the offset voltage doesn't matter; and neither does the impedance of the bias element, at least as long as it can be bypassed (for example, C3 and C4 act in series with D5-R11, bypassing them at high frequency), or is low enough not to care.

There does seem to be inconsistency here, such as Q1-Q4 being biased with diodes (presumably, they will match better than zeners would), but A2's output voltage isn't read by anything else, it's a free variable, and so any offset in Q1-Q4, D1-D4 is canceled out by the loop; thus I don't think the symmetry of this connection should be read as important.  Conversely, the loop closed by A1, Q1-Q4, R15, Q9-Q12, R4 and R5, means port 2 will be biased up by about 1.6V; give or take of course the state of A1, which depends on the Q14s (ope, I think one was meant to be Q13, but which one is ambiguous), and thus R1 setting and port 1.

I suspect this schematic is more representative of an example circuit as-tested, than a preferred embodiment; the random choice of biasing networks then is just what worked best for the particular JFETs that were pulled out of the bin.

Probably all three buffers can be replaced by op-amps, with Q5-Q8 being a single-unit type op-amp with the emitters exchanged for the power supply pins -- what became a common trick only somewhat later in the era of IC op-amps, based on the observation that quiescent current is a stable fixed offset through these pins, while output-pin current flows from one pin or the other respectively, with little overlap (class AB operation).

**Magic**

The "secret sauce", I think is the Q14s, acting as multipliers against the bias (R1 and related) and signal (R9, R10).  Beware their behavior depends critically on temperature; keep them cool, and probably matched (bond to the same heatsink).  Using higher-power types like KSD1691/KSB1151, or TIP31/32, etc., particularly if running at comparable bias to the original.